# invalid_client exception thrown by authlib even when following a working example for discord oauth2

Tags: flask, oauth-2.0, authlib

I built a flask app that logs in to discord using oauth2 and displays the users username and profile picture.
I followed the example https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/client/frameworks.html#using-oauth-2-0-to-log-in
and customized it with discord oauth information.

yet I kept getting an `invalid_client` exception thrown by authlib even though my program was correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to leave this out there in case someone else runs into the same problem:
authlib **will throw `invalid_client`** if your client secret is wrong too. I had misconfigured my client secret which caused authlib to throw this generic error